# Sort other columns within the groups formed by the values of first column in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to **keep the order of the first column** (i.e. col a) **untouched** (assuming first column is always sorted by default) and want to **perform sort / orderby** operation on rest of the columns (col b and col c) **within the groups formed by the values of the first column** (i.e. col a) **using Spark Dataframe**.

I've provided two examples below as per my requirement.

The real problem is to keep the order of first column  (i.e. col a) untouched and it should not undergo any sort / orderby operation.

I've tried below approaches to get the output but these approaches are not aligned to my requirement as I'm doing orderBy or first column as well which is incorrect.

```
    df.orderBy(col("a").desc(),col("b"),col("c")).show();

    df.orderBy(col("a").asc(),col("b"),col("c")).show();
```

**Input DF1:**

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  5|  3|
|  1|  7|  1|  9|
|  1|  6|  1|  8|
|  2|  5|  8|  3|
|  2|  6|  2|  7|
|  2|  9|  2|  7|
|  3|  4|  7|  4|
|  3|  1|  4|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

**Output DF1:**

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  5|  3|
|  1|  6|  1|  8|
|  1|  7|  1|  9|
|  2|  5|  8|  3|
|  2|  6|  2|  7|
|  2|  9|  2|  7|
|  3|  1|  4|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|  9|
|  3|  4|  7|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

**Input DF2:**

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  3|  4|  7|  4|
|  3|  1|  4|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|  9|
|  2|  5|  8|  3|
|  2|  6|  2|  7|
|  2|  9|  2|  7|
|  1|  2|  5|  3|
|  1|  7|  1|  9|
|  1|  6|  1|  8|
+---+---+---+---+
```

**Output DF2:**

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  3|  1|  4|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|  9|
|  3|  4|  7|  4|
|  2|  5|  8|  3|
|  2|  6|  2|  7|
|  2|  9|  2|  7|
|  1|  2|  5|  3|
|  1|  6|  1|  8|
|  1|  7|  1|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Not really possible

Comment: Sorry, but what was the thrust of the question given the answer?

Answer (score 1):

> Spark-2.4.3 here the code for retrieving your expected output

```
scala> var df1 =spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1,2,5,3),(1,7,1,9),(1,6,1,8),(2,5,8,3),(2,6,2,7),(2,9,2,7),(3,4,7,4),(3,1,4,2),(3,3,1,9))).toDF("a","b","c","d")


scala> df1.show
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  5|  3|
|  1|  7|  1|  9|
|  1|  6|  1|  8|
|  2|  5|  8|  3|
|  2|  6|  2|  7|
|  2|  9|  2|  7|
|  3|  4|  7|  4|
|  3|  1|  4|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

> For **df1** you can just order by all with default order(ascending)

```
scala> df1.orderBy("a","b","c","d").show
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  5|  3|
|  1|  6|  1|  8|
|  1|  7|  1|  9|
|  2|  5|  8|  3|
|  2|  6|  2|  7|
|  2|  9|  2|  7|
|  3|  1|  4|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|  9|
|  3|  4|  7|  4|
+---+---+---+---+

scala> var df2 = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((3,4,7,4),(3,1,4,2),(3,3,1,9),(2,5,8,3),(2,6,2,7),(2,9,2,7),(1,2,5,3),(1,7,1,9),(1,6,1,8))).toDF("a","b","c","d")


scala> df2.show
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  3|  4|  7|  4|
|  3|  1|  4|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|  9|
|  2|  5|  8|  3|
|  2|  6|  2|  7|
|  2|  9|  2|  7|
|  1|  2|  5|  3|
|  1|  7|  1|  9|
|  1|  6|  1|  8|
+---+---+---+---+
```

> For **df2** you can just order by col("a")  descending and other as default(ascending order) with default order(ascending)

```
scala> df2.orderBy(col("a").desc,col("b"),col("c"),col("d")).show

+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|
+---+---+---+---+
|  3|  1|  4|  2|
|  3|  3|  1|  9|
|  3|  4|  7|  4|
|  2|  5|  8|  3|
|  2|  6|  2|  7|
|  2|  9|  2|  7|
|  1|  2|  5|  3|
|  1|  6|  1|  8|
|  1|  7|  1|  9|
+---+---+---+---+
```

let me know if you have further any query.